# Google Slide font (Chinese font) changes when in presentation mode

Tags: google-slides

I was making a presentation using Google slides (in Chinese) and when I want to preview it in presentation mode, "some" of the font looks different from editor mode.

[The sample here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsPAS.png)

I've tried searching on Google and found only this [discussion thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/EIWqtiwkiME/rNCGkfLbt-QJ), but my problem is a little bit different. The font changes when I change it in the editor and in the presentation mode, the "character" somehow just looks different in presentation mode(the font style is correct). I have tried Safari, Chrome, Firefox, but all fails.

Is this like a bug only for Chinese characters? English seems perfectly fine to me. Does anyone have the same problem and knows how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this happens to many other languages (like JP, KO, etc.) as well.
It gets rendered differently from editor to presentation mode.

So, here is the quick fix for the issue.
Use 'ShowAsIs' Chrome extension to fix it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rt4xnAFFGik

Disclaimer: I am the developer of the extension.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped. :D

Comment: It's nice but it doesn't support animations in slides

Comment: Yes, since this extension uses editor pane in presentation mode. Coarse workaround is to make animation by using multiple slide. (No fancy animations)

Comment: Great app. Is there any way to make it to pdf AsIs?

Comment: But no solution for export as *.pdf ..?